# Why the superclass variable gets called though the method returns subclass object?

Tags: java

I know that the variable do not have polymorphism. If we do new Subclass().x then the value 20 will be printed during runtime.
But here the

```
Parent p = new Child();   
p.getObject();
```

getObject() of sublass will be called as the getObject of subclass will override the getObject() of super class.So the subclass method getObject() returns new Child(),so value printed should be that of Child.x ie 20.But the output is 10.Why the value of x is that of superclass??? I know that some posts are there related to this but not exactly this is explained anywhere.Please do help.

```
class MainClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Parent p = new Child();
      System.out.println(p.getObject().x);
     }
    }

    class Parent {
     int x = 10;

     public Parent getObject() {
      return new Parent();
     }
    } 

    class Child extends Parent {
     int x = 20;

     public Child getObject() {
      return new Child();
     }
    }
```

Comment: one doesnt simple override variables in java!

Comment: and.... you are doing  ***return new Parent();***

Comment: Instead of p.getObject().x if I write new Child().x then the value printed would be 20.But p.getObject() output is new Child()  which then converts into new Child().x but still output is 10 .Why????

Comment: getObject() in parent gets overriden by that of Child class getObject() right???

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing the variable `x` in class `Parent` because the *declared type* of `p.getObject()` is `Parent`.

BTW: accessing variables inside the object directly violates the most basic principle of OOP: *information hiding / encapsulation*! You should do this only for *data transfer objects / ValueObjects* which serve as pure data containers and  have no business logic of their own. And even there you should use getter/setter methods instead of direct variable access...

Comment: If the class fields are final, and you are not designing some library, then this principle will just force you to write redundant code in class. I don't think that these principles are meant to be used that strictly.

Comment: @matoni If you refuse to follow OO principles strictly, why do you use an OO language at all?

Comment: OO principles are good, but why would you overuse them, if situation does not require to use them at all? Blindly following principles will result in overpopulated classes with useless getters (not saying all getters are useless).

Comment: @matoni I rather do not think about if the situation might require OO principles or not especially since that may change in future. Applying them is never wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It is all about memory allocation in Java

Having `Parent p = new Child();` means that you are making an object on the heap that is of class Child and a reference to it named p, but this reference is meant to operate with objects of class Parent. 
So you are allocating an object of type Child but the reference is operating with Parent.

This means, the reference would not be able to see the x attribute of the Child. It would see only the Parent attributes.

Check [this](http://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory) out, and [this](https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/96742-how-memory-allocated-during-inheritance.html) as well

Answer (score 0):

What you did is called **shadowing**. If you declare variable with name that is already defined in reachable scope, that variable will shadow (hide) already defined variable. If you want to use variable from outer scope, you have to write absolute path of that variable or use accessor which is unique for that variable.

```
public class A {
    int a;

    public A(int a) {
        System.out.println(a); // arg "a" has shadowed class field
        System.out.println(this.a);

        // that's why we are using this assignment:
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

The same happened in you example. `child.x` has shadowed `parent.x` field. If object reference is of `Child` type i. e. `Child c = new Child();` , then by default the nearest reachable variable `x` will be used (`Child.x`). If your object reference is of `Parent` type i. e. `Parent p = new Parent();`, then again the nearest reachable `x` will be used (`Parent.x`). The same applies for `Parent p = new Child();` since `p` is `new Child` but upcasted to `Parent` type, thus `p.x` will display `Parent.x` value.

You just have to remember, that **polymorphism does not apply to class fields**. You can't override field value unless it is wrapped in some getter.

So, If you need to override displayed value, you have to wrap this value in some getter, which will be overridden by `Child` class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        System.out.println(p.getObject().getValue()); // 20
        System.out.println(p.getValue()); // 20
    }

    static class Parent {
        int x = 10;

        public int getValue() {return x;}

        public Parent getObject() {return new Parent();}
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {
        int x = 20;

        @Override
        public int getValue() {return x;} // return Child.x

        @Override
        public Child getObject() {return new Child();}
    }
}
```